# Customizing the Stockchart range selector buttons from HighCharts library in GWT (and Javascript in general)

Tags: javascript, gwt, highcharts

I'm using the HighCharts library for GWT, and I'm having a problem.

I'm trying something like this: [stock chart example](http://jsfiddle.net/WCabG/3/). The only thing I'm interested on for this question is the `buttons` property inside `rangeSelector`, in which I want to customize the button texts). On javascript the code is like this:

```
rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 3,
                text: '3dias'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1w'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6MS'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1ano'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 3
        }
```

Now I'm trying to do the same in GWT, using the method setOption() on the chart. But nothing seems to work.

I think I'm having trouble because the `buttons` property needs an array of properties, and that's what I can't figure out how to solve.

Something I tried:

```
chart.setOption("/rangeSelector/buttons", 
      new String[]{"{type: 'day', count: 1, text: '1dia'}", "{type: 'day', count: 1, text: '1dia'}"});`
```

This is the best I could come up with, which creates two empty buttons and with no actions.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

**UPDATE: (Dec 13, 2012)** 
After the accepted answer was given, I needed to set the button witdh.
For that just use:

```
buttonTheme: {
    width: 80
}
```

something like:

```
rangeSelector: {
                selected: 2,
                inputBoxStyle: {
                    top: '40px',
                    right: '10px'},
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'week',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1 semana'
                }],
                buttonTheme: {
                    width: 80
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following:

```
 String rangeSelectorConfig =  " {\n" +
            "                buttons: [{\n" +
            "                    type: 'day',\n" +
            "                    count: 3,\n" +
            "                    text: '3dias'\n" +
            "                }, {\n" +
            "                    type: 'week',\n" +
            "                    count: 1,\n" +
            "                    text: '1w'\n" +
            "                }]" +
            "            }" ;
 JSONValue config = JSONParser.parseLenient(rangeSelectorConfig);
 chart.setOption("/rangeSelector", config);
```

`Chart` class (with help of `Configurable`) doesn't parse JSON objects for you, so buttons in your code were passed as string literals to native HightCharts JS.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. Just one question though, why did you put the "\n" there? Any reason in special? I'm asking because it works without them.

Comment: It is just formatting hint of my IDEA :), on copy/paste of string literals to Java code. No reasons to add them.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought it could be any kind of pattern, or good practice or something. Just one more question, if you know. Is it possible to change the buttons' length? Cuz now if I add longer texts, it'll be messy.

Comment: I am not sure, actually. But have you tried to simply pass 'width' attribute for 'button'?